# Check a column in dataframe with startswith

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a tweet dataframe. I want to check if a text is a retweet. First, I wrote a function to check if a tweet is a retweet:

```
def isRetweet(tweet):
  check_RT = tweet.startswith("RT ")
  if check_RT ==True:
    return check_RT
  else:
    return check_RT
```

Then I check if any line in a column contains a retweet.

```
text = tweets['tweet_text']
check_retweet = isRetweet(text) 
print(check_retweet)
```

It returns this error `'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Is there anyway to apply my function to individual line/text within the column? Or is there anything wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`str` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods), and you also don't really need the function:

```
tweets['is_retweet'] = tweets['tweet_text'].str.startswith('RT')
```

If you insist on having a function you should use `apply`:

```
tweets['is_retweet'] = tweets['tweet_text'].apply(lambda tweet: tweet.startswith('RT'))
```

Both of these examples will create a new boolean column.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your df using lambda checking if the text in that column starts with RT or not

```
tweets[lambda x: x['tweet_text'].str.startswith('RT')]
```